# Gurobi quicksum syntax in python

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I have an optimization problem using Python and Gurobi. I wrote the constraints using quicksum, but I got syntax error

```
m.modelSense = gp.GRB.MINIMIZE
m.setObjective(t)
m.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(-1 * mu[i] * x[k]))+ (gp.quicksum(sigma[j] * x[k])) - 1.05*x[200] -t ) <= 0 for i in range(1,200) for j in range(1,200) for k in range(1,200)
m.addConstrs(gp.quicksum(x[k])) = 100 for k in range(1,200)

m.optimize()
```

I need suggestions to help me solve this error

Comment: What syntax error do you get?

Comment: `... = 100 for k in range(1,200)` doesn't seem like valid Python to me. What is your intent for that line? Solve for 200 values of `k` (from 1 to 199), iterating over it? If so, write it in a normal for loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem solved, the syntax wasn't correct

```
m.modelSense = gp.GRB.MINIMIZE
m.setObjective(t)
m.addConstr(
    gp.quicksum(-1 * mu[i] * x[i] for i in range(199)) + gp.quicksum(sigma[i] * x[i] for i in range(199)) - 1.05* x[199] - t <=0
    )  

m.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i] for i in range(200)) == 100 ) 
m.addConstr(x[i] >= 0)
m.optimize()
```